# How to create a function for recursively generating iterating functions

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion, user-input

I currently have a bit of Python code that looks like this:

```
for set_k in data:
    for tup_j in set_k:
        for tup_l in tup_j:
```

The problem is, I'd like the number of nested *for* statements to differ based on user input. If I wanted to create a function which generated n number of *for* statements like those above, how might I go about doing that?

Comment: You could seperate the loop into a function, then you could recursively call the function. Exactly how it would work though would depend on the use case.

Answer (score 8):

```
def nfor(data, n=1):
    if n == 1:
        yield from iter(data)
    else:
        for element in data:
            yield from nfor(element, n=n-1)
```

Demo:

```
>>> for i in nfor(['ab', 'c'], n=1):
...     print(i)
...     
ab
c
>>> for i in nfor(['ab', 'c'], n=2):
...     print(i)
...     
a
b
c
```

Comment: Note that the `yield from` syntax is Python 3 only.

Comment: Is it really worth noting a 5+ years old feature of the language any more?

Comment: [Python 3.3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) to be exact @BrendanAbel.

Comment: Eh, I think many people still use Python 2 for legacy code @wim. OTHO, I think you do have a point. If people still haven't ported to Python 3 by now, that's not really your problem.

Comment: Unless the OP specified a lower Python version, these kind of comments are just litter.  Python 2 EOL is < 2 years.

Comment: Yeah, I know Python's ending support for Python 2 in 2020. Like I said, there are still people out their who for one reason or another haven't ported their legacy code to Python 3. _In my opinion_, and Given SO's popularity, _I would_ note that code in my uses certain Python 3 features. But I do understand where you're coming from.

Comment: @wim Yeah, I may be a bit influenced by the fact that I work in an industry that is still almost completely Python2.  I'd say it's still widely used enough that it's worth at least a *mention*.